# Why is this MySQL query causing an error?

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `metadata` (`group_id`, `key`, `value`) 
VALUES ("19", "originality", "2") 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (`group_id` = `19`, `key`=`originality`, `value`=`2`)
```

The table:

```
group_id | key | value
----------------------------------------
```

`group_id` and `key` both have a `UNIQUE` index.

The error happens when I try to run the query when a row already exists with the id 19. The way I want the query to function is, if there is no row with that id, insert it and if there is update it instead of inserting a new row.

The error message I get is the typical:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, comment was wrong

Comment: I think you've truncated the error message just where it started to get interesting.

Comment: @nurdglaw edited to include full error.

Comment: @TK123, thanks. The dialog box clearly isn't from the query you're posting - it mentions "submission_group_id", while the posted query refers to "group_id". It suggests, pretty strongly, that the statement is OK up to and including `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, so points you _directly_ to the open bracket that glglgl spotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if a `(` should follow the `UPDATE` keyword - I think not. So try

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `group_id` = 19, `key`='originality', `value`=2
```

(or replace `group_id` with `submission_group_id` - your error message doesn't seem to match  the original query)

Answer (score 1):

you can only use ` on table columns and table names, not for data.
data should use ' or "

like:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `group_id` = 19, `key`="originality", `value`=2
```

Comment: I still get the same error after changing the back ticks around the values to be single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The quote tag must be the ' character not the ` character.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is no row with that id, insert it and if there is update it instead of inserting a new row.

If you want to do this you should try statement like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE ColumnName='somevalue')
    UPDATE sometable SET (...) WHERE ColumnName='somevalue'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```